# Location of stack canary relative to ebp

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to get used to stack canary mechanism.

While I'm doing some searching, I found that in some usages, stack canary is placed at %ebp - 0x8, and some other usages, at %ebp -0xC.

Is entry %ebp - 0x4 also can be used for storing stack canary?
And also, is there any compiler options for designating this varying behavior?

Thanks, always

Comment: Always somewhere between the return address and the locals. Can you show some examples of the varying behavior that you're seeing? Perhaps we can infer what the difference is.

Comment: If compilers place it below other call-preserved registers they `push`, that would explain the difference.  There's no reason to expect it to be at a fixed location relative to EBP, even in a debug build where functions use EBP as a traditional frame pointer at all.

Comment: Tons of codes on the net shows various behavior, and it seems I got the answer. To whom may it concern, one may look up to the terms of stack alignment. Thanks for all!